# R: parsing text file of quotations / splitting into paragraphs

Tags: r, parsing, paragraph, quotations

I'm looking for an R solution to the problem of parsing a text file of quotations (as below) giving a data.frame with one observation per quote, and variables `text` and `source` as described below.

```
DIAGRAMS are of great utility for illustrating certain questions of vital statistics by
conveying ideas on the subject through the eye, which cannot be so readily grasped when
contained in figures.
--- Florence Nightingale, Mortality of the British Army, 1857

To give insight to statistical information it occurred to me, that making an
appeal to the eye when proportion and magnitude are concerned, is the best and
readiest method of conveying a distinct idea. 
--- William Playfair, The Statistical Breviary (1801), p. 2


Regarding numbers and proportions, the best way to catch the imagination is to speak to the eyes.
--- William Playfair, Elemens de statistique, Paris, 1802, p. XX.

The aim of my carte figurative is to convey promptly to the eye the relation not given quickly by numbers requiring mental calculation.
--- Charles Joseph Minard
```

Here, each quotation is a paragraph, separated from the next by `"\n\n"`. Within the paragraph, all lines up to the one beginning `---` comprise the `text` and what follows `---` is the `source`.

I imagine I could solve this if I could first first split the text lines into paragraphs (separated by `'\\n\\n+'` (2 or more blank lines), but I'm having trouble doing that.

Comment: Can you share with us the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the initial text loaded in `rawText` variable

```
library(stringr)

strsplit(rawText, "\n\n")[[1]] %>% 
  str_split_fixed("\n--- ", 2) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c("text", "source"))
```

Comment: To me, this seems like the simplest, tidiest solution so far.  What I was missing was (a) the use of `strsplit`, needing either `unlist` or `[[1]]`; (b) `setNames()` for assigning names in a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the bulk of what you need to achieve. I assume you already have the file in a length-1 character vector called `txt`:

```
library(tidyverse)

txt                                             %>% 
strsplit("\n{2,5}")                             %>% 
unlist()                                        %>% 
lapply(function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "--- "))) %>%
{do.call("rbind", .)}                           %>%
as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)         %>%
setNames(c("Text", "Source"))                    ->
df
```

If you then tidy up the text by replacing newlines with spaces, you get the following:

```r
df$Text <- gsub("\n", " ", df$Text)
as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Text                                              Source                             
#>   <chr>                                             <chr>                              
#> 1 "DIAGRAMS are of great utility for illustrating ~ Florence Nightingale, Mortality of~
#> 2 "To give insight to statistical information it o~ William Playfair, The Statistical ~
#> 3 "Regarding numbers and proportions, the best way~ William Playfair, Elemens de stati~
#> 4 "The aim of my carte figurative is to convey pro~ Charles Joseph Minard
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as my answer below. In this case, I would recommend just loading `magrittr` since `tidyverse` is a very large dependency to just get the pipe (`%>%`) operator.

Comment: @MarcusA. I'm quite a fan of `magrittr`, but my experience on SO is that most (though by no means all) users already have some or all of the `tidyverse` loaded. Also, for display purposes I wanted to show the result as a `tibble` rather than a data frame. I was just being lazy!

Comment: 100% agree most have `tidyverse`. I was purposely trying to sneak in some code optimization/break down the black box of `tidyverse` content into the thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text file is `quote.txt` in working directory.

**R base** solution: split it 2 times: (1) by `\n\n` and (2) by `---`, then combine into data frame.

```
quote <- readLines("quote.txt")
quote <- paste(quote, collapse = "\n")

DF <- strsplit(unlist(strsplit(quote, "\n\n")), "---")
DF <- data.frame(text= trimws(sapply(DF, "[[", 1)), 
           source = trimws(sapply(DF, "[[", 2)))
```

Output

```
DF
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 # text
# 1     DIAGRAMS are of great utility for illustrating certain questions of vital statistics by\nconveying ideas on the subject through the eye, which cannot be so readily grasped when\ncontained in figures.
# 2 To give insight to statistical information it occurred to me, that making an\nappeal to the eye when proportion and magnitude are concerned, is the best and\nreadiest method of conveying a distinct idea.
# 3                                                                                                           Regarding numbers and proportions, the best way to catch the imagination is to speak to the eyes.
# 4                                                                     The aim of my carte figurative is to convey promptly to the eye the relation not given quickly by numbers requiring mental calculation.
#                                                          source
# 1     Florence Nightingale, Mortality of the British Army, 1857
# 2       William Playfair, The Statistical Breviary (1801), p. 2
# 3 William Playfair, Elemens de statistique, Paris, 1802, p. XX.
# 4                                         Charles Joseph Minard
```